# Is it possible to ignore SQL table alias?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, alias

Is it in anyway possible to reference a strongly typed SQL table object directly, even after it has been aliased?

For example, the following script renders a `The multi-part identifier "dbo.MyTable.Col3" could not be bound` exception:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
    INNER JOIN dbo.AnotherTable AT ON
        MT.Col1 = AT.Col2
WHERE
    dbo.MyTable.Col3 = 'Foo'
```

Comment: Interesting question, but what led you to this?

Comment: I have a piece of dynamic SQL that gets concatenated based on an input param. For example (referencing the above script), the whole `SELECT` and `FROM` clause are the dynamic part. The `WHERE` clause is concatenated based on whether a `WHERE` clause was passed in as a parameter. Now the user who would execute the procedure does not necessarily know the different aliases, only the table name.

Comment: If you don't control the `FROM` clause, then they could easily include the same table multiple times - that's one of the key features that using aliases allows to happen - in which case how would you have expected this to work in such a situation?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly DTU. The dynamic part is stored as a column value and is fixed. The `WHERE` clause is variable based on the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot.

To quote from [`FROM` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx):

> The table name cannot be used if an alias is defined.